# tinyMCE get the current selected HTML element

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I've an editor in which I can select text and display it by the following code :

```
alert(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent({format : "html"}));
```

the issue is the function returns only text and not HtmlElement. So I can't see, for example, the node which encapsulate this selected text. 
I would like to get the content but by an HtmlElement to deal with nodes.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at `getNode()`:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
```

The API calls available on a selection are documented here:  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.selection/

Comment: Okay I tried that before and it always returned me `body` but now I retried that and it works, thank you